# iOS - Reuse same TableViewController with Generics

Tags: swift, uitableview, generics, reusability

I have followed some great articles in order to implement a BaseTableViewController, reusable with Generics.

It is working, here is a quick example :

```
if let mountains = viewModel?.model["mountain"] as? ResponseMountain {
     let mountainTableViewController = BaseTableViewController(items: mountains.result, config: { (cell, item) in
         cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
      }, style: .plain)
      mountainTableViewController.title = "Mountains"
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mountainTableViewController, animated: true)
 }
```

Imagine I want to display a simple list of mountain ranges from my country and when you select a mountain range, you display a list of all massifs available within this mountain range.

This is why I want to reuse the same TableViewController, but with different data.

I don't know how to handle it with my generics implementation.

Here is my current implementation :

```
final class BaseTableViewController<Item>: UITableViewController {

    var items: [Item] {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    let config: (UITableViewCell, Item) -> ()

    init(items: [Item], config: @escaping (UITableViewCell, Item) -> (), style: UITableViewStyle) {
        self.items = items
        self.config = config
        super.init(style: style)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        config(cell, item)
        return cell
    }
}
```

It's efficient, simple, and it works for different use case.

But how can I implement a custom `didSelectRowAt` with generics, in order to push an instance of the same BaseViewController with data from the row I just selected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it the same way you're handing `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Pass another closure into `init` with the type `(Item) -> ()`. Then call that closure in `didSelectRowAt` ad pass the selected item.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    didSelect(item)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didn't think about it. This is why SO is so useful, it gives you this "external point of view" you often need in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably take an approach like this:

First off, define the protocol for our table data items and an implementation object to go with it:

```
protocol TableItem {
    var title: String { get set }
    var items: [TableItem]? { get set }
}

struct TableItemImp: TableItem {
    var title: String
    var items: [TableItem]?
}
```

Next define an extension of UITableViewCell to handle the cell configuration:

```
extension UITableViewCell {

    func configure<T>(with item: T) {

        if let item = item as? TableItem {

            // configure based on TableItem type
            textLabel?.text = item.title

        }
    }
}
```

Here's an updated implementation of your base tableview class to work with this setup and present another base table view controller with the list defined in the sublist:

```
final class BaseTableViewController<Item>: UITableViewController {

    let cellId = "cellIdentifier"
    var items: [Item] = [] {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    init(items: [Item], style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(style: style)
        configure(with: items)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    internal func configure(with items: [Item] = []) {
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        self.items = items
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(with: item)
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        guard let vc = getDetailController(item: item) else {
            return
        }
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    internal func getDetailController(item: Item) -> UITableViewController? {
        guard let item = item as? TableItem, let items = item.items else {
            return nil
        }

        return BaseTableViewController<TableItem>(items: items, style: .plain)
    }
}
```

I tested it using this setup code.

```
func setupTableView() {
    let items = [
        TableItemImp(title: "Alps", items: [
            TableItemImp(title: "One", items: nil)
            ]),
        TableItemImp(title: "Appalachian", items: [
            TableItemImp(title: "Two", items: nil)
            ]),
        TableItemImp(title: "Rockies", items: [
            TableItemImp(title: "Three", items: nil)
            ])
    ]
    let tableVC = BaseTableViewController<TableItem>.init(items: items, style: .plain)
    present(tableVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I call this code in a test view controller in `viewDidAppear()` which presents your base table view controller with the top level list. If you click on `"Rockies"` then it will present another list controller displaying a cell with the title `"Three"`